# What is the command that executes when you save image as... on the internet?

Tags: ubuntu, hotkeys

I'm trying to see if i can set up a command through compiz to where I attach a super+right click hotkey to auto pull up the save image as screen quicker or even eliminate the need to rename the image, does anyone know what i would put in the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Firefox, you can possibly use the [keyconfig](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994) extension to set-up a keyboard shortcut within that application to save a screenshot.

I seriously doubt there's any integration between Gnome/Compiz and Firefox that would let you invoke Firefox features like this using a shortcut.

Comment: I have been looking into keyconfig and while it doesn't do exactly what i want it gave me an idea and im looking up what value in about:config pulls up the right click menu in hopes of altering it, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu executes nothing when you save image as… on the internet, if I understand your question correctly.

You use firefox, when surfing the internet? And point your mouse to a certain image on a webpage, and then perform `save as ...`?

So that would be firefox, not ubuntu, which saves the image, and I dont know of a possibility, without reprogramming and recompiling firefox, to add macros, to define your own hotkeys. But maybe there is a plugin, so if I'm right, search the firefox-plugin-collection.

But in the questions body, it more sounds like you're searching for a screenshot-tool? No?

If so,

```
apropos screenshot
```

should give you some installed screenshottools, and

```
man gnome-screenshot 
man import
```

should give you the available arguments, to control the program.

Then you could bind a script, which uses the screenshottool, to some hotkey.

Comment: Yea, you are right, i mistakenly believed there was a connection between X and how firefox saves images, before i read your responses i was looking into bin commands through nautilus, it would've been a headache had i continued